# Android Studio : Open Android Module in Android Studio option is missing in flutter project

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-studio-3.0

I am developing a flutter app for both iOS and Android. When generating the APK, I prefer to use Android studio (my default IDE is VSCODE). However, when I go to **Tools > Flutter** I do not see  **Open Android Module in Android Studio** option. I do see **Open iOS Module in Xcode**.

I followed couple of SO answers, even tried replacing `android.iml` file from a working project. Nothing happened. I re-cloned my project from BitBucket because sometimes the Android Studio was fine when the project is freshly from repo, but this time, that didn't work either.

I Also tried opening the `gradle` file and looking for the option (as explained in one SO answer), that didn't work too.

However I noticed, few issues.

1. In the folder structure, the root folder is replaced by the `flutter` icon. in projects where I have no issues with, the folder icon is `folder`.
2. In here I see `.dart_tool` folder. In working apps with no issue, I do not see this folder.
3. I do not have an `android.iml` file. In other projects I did.

Below is my folder structure in a nutshell. Whats going on here and how to fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Simplest solution**

1. Open flutter project
2. Go to android folder
3. open manfiest file
4. On the top right you will see option `open module in android studio`
5. click on this option

**Solution 2**:-
Import your android project as a project in android studio

Comment: in Android Studio 4.0.1 there is no  “Flutter commands” banner at the top of the editor with a link labeled Open for Editing in Android Studio

Comment: gradlew is missing (when Studio kicks in the gradle build automatically)

Answer (score 4):

When you don't see any options to

> open module in android studio

because of missing `.iml` files caused by `.gitignore` file, follow simple steps.

1. Click on **File** and choose **Open..**
2. Now in the opened dialog choose `android` folder of **example** flutter project under your plugin module. For e.g if ***test*** is your plugin with **example** as it's app then you need to select and click `Ok`

> test\example\android

[image: Reference image of]
3. Then wait for Android Studio to sync and download necessary jar files.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use this command in the root directory of your project, it will create some missing files and it will definitely work.

```
flutter create --platforms=android .
```

Now just right click to Android folder

[image]